# Table view cell background not changing wholly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

See [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGiyx.png)

I am trying to change the background color of a selected cell to white. However I see that some areas are still in grey.
How do I avoid this?

```
self.tableView.selectRow(at: defaultLangIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)
    let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: defaultLangIndexPath)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    selectedCell.accessoryView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

I cannot unselect the cell because I want the highlighted accessory image and want it to work as expected.

Comment: on uitalbeview didselect method get the cell reference (you can get the cell providing indexpath ) change the cell background color to expected color, As this seems to very basic , write down the complete problem if this not expected.. default selected cell color is gray, you can disable the same by cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone

Comment: The easiest way around this would also be set `selectedCell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = .white`. You're using custom accessory view but it's frame is not filling the whole space provided for accessory view. This is why you're seeing the grey area there.

Comment: @inokey, tried it. that didnt work

Comment: What you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Try to set some plain UIView as accessory view in your cellForRow method. Give it some other color like red. And then see what happens.

Comment: you need add a customview on background and change its color rather than chaning cell background color, you accessory view wont be impacted in this way.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this `UITableViewCell` has a property called `selectedBackgroundView` which is `nil` at the initialization.

So you can initialize it with simple `UIView()` and set the background color of `selectedBackgroundView` in tableViewCell’s `setSelected:`  method.

```
class SelectionCell: UITableViewCell {
  func awakeFromNib() { 
    ...
    self.selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
    // this view can be initialised in awakeFromNib 
       or UITableViewCell's initialiser methods.
    ...
  }

  override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    self.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = selected ? .white : .clear
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

***A: By setting it in Storyboard***

Go to Storyboard, select the cell, go to attribute inspector (at the top right), on selection, set None

[image]

***B: By Cell Subclass***

Make sure to set this custom cell type on your Storyboard Identity Inspector or programatically.

```
class WhiteBackgroundCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        selectionStyle = .none
        //or for custom color
        //let background View = UIView()
        //backgroundView.backgroundColor = .white
        //selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView

        //other cell setting
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        //do something
    }
}
```

***C: By TableViewDelegate***

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)else{return}
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Options **A and B are fine**. Option **C is not a good practice**, but not sure what u want to achieve. Since that delegate is intended to do some logic/triggers, not setting cell background. Plus u will need to change background color to normal state and deselected.